# Calling a Smart Contract function using Web3

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have the following code to call a smart contract function:

```
async function addManager(){
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    var deployedNetwork = MarketplaceArtifact.networks[networkId];
    var marketplace = new web3.eth.Contract(
        MarketplaceArtifact.abi,
        deployedNetwork.address,
    );

    var address = document.getElementById('addressField').value;

    const { AddManager } = marketplace.methods;
    const response = await AddManager(address, { from: this.account }).call();
    console.log(response);
}
```

Why is the console.log giving me such a response Shouldn't the call return the return value form the smart contract?

[image]

Comment: As you are using `await` in the function mark `addManager` as `async`. Though not sure it will solve your issue.

Comment: the Function is indeed marked as async. Forgot to include that part.

Comment: please use await whenever you try to communicate with web3

Comment: It looks like `AddManager` function is going to update something in your contract. Any function that changes the state of your contract, you need to use `.send()` function instead of `.call()`. `.call()` is used only for fetching data from contract.